# WPF Listbox with custom item template

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls

I am developing a demo app that interacts with Twitter. I want to create a control like the twitter website has, the tweets list.

I did the following, it is a listbox with multiple stackpanels inside. How could I create these controls taking performance in consideration. Take a look at the list:

```
<ListBox Margin="50">
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="60"
                                       >James T. Kirk</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="35"
                                       >Rank: Captain</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Position: Commanding Officer</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       Foreground="#AAAAAA">Current action: Sleeping</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="50"
                                       >Spock</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="30"
                                       >Rank: Commander</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Position: Executive (First)</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       Foreground="#FFAAAA">Current action: Out for duty</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="40"
                                       >Leonard McCoy</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="22"
                                       >Rank: Lt. Commander</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Position: Chief Medical Officer</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       Foreground="#AAAAAA">Current action: Sleeping</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="40"
                                       >Montgomery Scott</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="22"
                                       >Rank: Lt. Commander</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Position: Chief Engineer</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       Foreground="#FFAAAA">Current action: Out for duty</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="30"
                                       >Hikaru Sulu</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Rank: Lieutenant</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Position: Helm Officer</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       Foreground="#AAAAAA">Current action: Sleeping</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="30"
                                       >Nyota Uhura</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Rank: Lieutenant</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Position: Communications Officer</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       Foreground="#AAAAAA">Current action: Sleeping</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="30"
                                       >Pavel Chekov</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Rank: Ensign</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Position: Navigator</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       Foreground="#AAAAAA">Current action: Sleeping</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="30"
                                       >Christine Chapel</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Rank: Enlisted Nurse</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Position: Nurse</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       Foreground="#AAAAAA">Current action: Sleeping</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock FontSize="30"
                                       >Janice Rand</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Rank: Enlisted Yeoman</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       >Position: Yeoman</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18"
                                       Foreground="#AAAAAA">Current action: Sleeping</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

To test it, just create a WPF windows project, and copy & paste the code inside the "Grid" element element and just run. You will see a listbox that is similar of what I want. I need it to be good at:

1)Performance
2)Binding
3)Interactivity

UPDATE: **I am not asking you to review this code**. I am asking you to see it, **so you can understand better what I want to achieve**.

UPDATE 2: I was going to post the model, but it is a little complex. So I am posting this link to show kinda of what I want to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmDKM.jpg

In the left we have the clicked item, it holds text, media content, other buttons with Glyphs.

In the right we see the list itself, if it goes bigger than vertical size, it shows the vertical scroll on the right side.

```
//I would do something like this:
var tweets = await TwitterUserHelper.GetTweetsAsync();
foreach(var tweet in tweets) {
    MyListBox.Items.Add(new CustomListboxItemFromTemplate(tweet));
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think you should read the question before trying to close it. It is very annoying to deal with your behavior.

Comment: @SilvioSantos You didn't actually ask a question in what you posted, so it isn't clear what kind of help you want. Also, there is no binding in the XAML above: you might want to look into MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) as this is the preferred way of doing things like this in WPF. If you took that approach, you would bind your `ListBox` control to a collection, then that control would take care of UI virtualization for you, thus helping with performance.

Comment: I Agree with Steven Rands, there's no way you'll get DataBinding and virtualization without a proper data model to bind to.

Comment: Ok, that is much better. I will update the question with the model in minutes. Thanks.